# Checking available room in Qt Dock

Tags: qt, qt4, qdockwidget

I'm using Qt4 and I have a menu option that programmatically adds a new dock widget into a dock area.
Unfortunately, if the dock area is already full, adding a new dock widget will cause it to resize the dock widgets below their minimum size, leading to overlapping widgets and worse.

How can I verify there is enough space in a dock area to add a new dock widget?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of determining available space, could you instead use the [tabifyDockWidget](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.6/qmainwindow.html#tabifyDockWidget) feature of QT docking? (Available as of QT 4.2 ... I think).

Comment: No, this would cause the new widget to just be a tab on top of the existing widget, which is completely different behavior.